# Managing Images in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am designing a website in which users can send other uses photos they have taken. I have set up MySQL and PHP pages to have users sign up, sign in, etc., but my question is, what do I need to do to have users upload images that are assigned to go to another user? I was thinking something along the lines of having ID's for all the images, and then certain users would have access to the certain ID's of images. Any information is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

going by the info here, you would probably need the following setup:

tables:

```
userrelationship(userid, friendid)

images(id, imagepath, userid)

sharedimages(id, originaluserid, friendid, imageid)
```

that's real basic, but it should start you off.

Comment: Does this work? accounts(id, email, username, password) images(id, uploader-username, description, receiver-username, path)

Comment: as far as accounts go, yea thats fine if thats all the info needed to register the user, but Images I would use the unique id's for users instead of their "usernames"...later on if you want to show a relationship of images and username you can just write a simple select statement with inner join to the accounts table to display it.

Comment: I really appreciate this wealth of information. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like this

```
table - images
image_id | image_source | image_from | image_to
    1      source of img   user id     user id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options and it is up to you on how you want to implement it.

First option: Have them upload the photo, assign it/rename it a unique hash or id, put it in a table that is associated with the user:

```
id | hash | user_id
```

Second option: You can always store the image in your MySQL database as a blob, but that can be burdensome as you will probably need a lot more information.

```
id | blob (base64 encoded data) | name | extension | user_id
```

And the rest of the options are somewhere in between.  Basically, set up the table solely for images, and if you want to add permissions, put it in a separate table, and when a user tries to access it, just check the image owners permissions:

```
user_id | permissions
```

If the image owner only wants pictures to be viewed by themselves, add that permission type, or if they want friends, or friends or friends, or anyone, you can create those separate permission flags.

Now if you are looking for permissions per image, then you would need to attach a permissions field to the image table.  Again, you could do a combo of both and if the permissions field in the image table is null, you can fall back on the user's default permissions.

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be different than either of the above users'.

```
table - image
id (primary) | source | date_added | etc...
int            varchar  int(10)

table - user
id (primary) | date_added | name
int            int(10)      varchar

table - user_image
user_id (primary) | image_id (primary) | date_added | permissions
int                 int                  int(10)      int
```

Basically, have a table for user, and a table for images.  Then, have a table to define user-image pairs.  That way, you can keep images and users separate and create links between them.  Create new rows in the `user_image` table to give image access to other users, and use the `permissions` column to control exactly what those users' rights are with respect to controlling those images.

It's a very flexible system.  Hope that helps?